# Simple query with foreach loop does not work, but without works

Tags: php, sql, pdo, foreach

I have a problem with query that makes no sense.

```
public function getGroup(){

    if(2 > 0){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products ";
        $array = array(1);
        foreach($array as $n){
            $query .= " AND ID '$n'";
        }
        return $query;
    } else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = 1 ";
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense, we need some context.

Comment: (1) What is this supposed to be:  "AND ID '$n'"?  (2) Printing out the query after you create it would seem to be an obvious way to see the problem.

Comment: Your query will look something like `SELECT * FROM products AND ID <someId>`, which isn't correct. You're lacking the `WHERE` clause. At least that's what I can understand from the above code.

Comment: `$query .= " AND ID '$n'";` remove AND rather then AND use WHERE. `$query .= " Where ID '$n'";`

Comment: Thos typos will get you every single time. **Please** do not make edits to your original question because those might invalidate good answers.

Comment: Please do not continue to make stealth edits to your question.

Comment: Echo your query and you will see errors. "WHERE" is missing and conditions in WHERE starts with AND

Comment: sorry my mistake. doesn't work with WHERE

Comment: query is the same

Answer (score 2):

There is no WHERE in your if statement. So your query will look like: `SELECT * FROM products AND ID '$n'`.... Notice also no `=` after `ID`.

```
    public function getGroup(){

        if(2 > 0){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE";
            $array = array(1);
            $i=0;
            foreach($array as $n){
                if($i==0) {
                    $query .= " ID = '$n'";
                }
                else {
                    $query .= " AND ID = '$n'";
                }
                $i++;
            }
            return $query;
        } else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = 1 ";
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You were close, but still not correct. Now OPs query will look like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE AND ID = <someID>`. Set a condition for the first iteration of the `foreach` loop to not add the `AND` part.

Comment: Still not correct `$n` doesn't exist before the `foreach`.

Comment: Saw it just now. might work as I have the answer now, not 100% sure though

Comment: `$i` will always be `0` as you're not incrementing the value.

Comment: looking better now?

Comment: There you go. Good job.

Comment: Fixed... @JayBlanchard

Comment: fixed... Lots and lost more!

Answer (score 0):

i think you want like this

```
public function getGroup(){
    if(2 > 0){
        $array = array(1);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID in ('$array')";           
        return $query;
    } else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID = 1 ";
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whay do you "think" that?  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: i think s78 want record according to ids array

Comment: If you think that make it part of your answer.

Comment: and what you it is not make that this ans is incorrect

Comment: The answer may be correct, it just does not contain an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way.